# Fourier series phasor form and sin/cos form

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

[image]

can anyone give me a link on how to convert the forms (from phasor to sine/cos and vice versa)? I am new to this and I can't find the convertion table with a valid explaination.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I just want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

$$\cos (x+y) =\cos x \cos y - \sin x \sin y$$

$$\sin (x+y) =\sin x \cos y + \cos x \sin y$$

And,

$$A\cos x + B \sin X=\sqrt{A^2+B^2}\cos (x+\arctan(B/A))$$

$$C \cos (x+\phi)= C(\cos \phi \cos x-\sin \phi \sin x)$$

$$|A|e^{i\phi} e^{ix}+|A|e^{-i\phi} e^{-ix}=2|A|\cos (x+\phi)$$

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not getting how does it link to the complex number j that is present in the fourier coefficient?

Comment: it was not me. I was wondering who did it too lol. Cause if he had to downvote it the least he could do was give an answer himself

Comment: OK.  No worry.  I added another expression.  Please let me know how else I can help you.

Comment: thank you. Its not too clear to me yet (still new to this). But it gave me somewhere to start. thank you

Comment: There i marked it as answer, (i cant upvote yet because my reputation is not high enough)